# Deploy web.config with msi file

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-config, config

Back to .NET 2.0 -- I have a Web Site project which hosts a web service and I use Deployment Project to create MSI file to deploy the Web Site. The specifics of the situation require to deploy a new web.config when installing the MSI. How can I include my web.config into MSI file created by the Deployment Project?

(Not sure if Config Transforms are possible with Web Sites in .NET 2.0)

Answer (score 0):

To include the file to MSI for deployment, right-click on the Deployment Project => Add => File... and select the file. It can be any existing file. There is nothing special here about Web Site or web.config.